# C# Form Freezing While Receiving Bytes After Packets Sent

Tags: c#, sockets

Ok so, some of you guys may not understand from the title, but i am trying to work on something for a game in C#. It involves connecting to a socket so that i can send packets to the server and have everything work.

But the problem is that when i go to receive after sending a packet, the program just freezes all together, and i cant even get a response to make sure its working. Here, ill show you a bit of what i mean by showing my code.

```
private void sendRawPackets(Socket s, string packet)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}\0", packet));
        s.Send(data);
    }

    private void gethash(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadLine();
                logkey = "";
                logkey = result;
            }
        }
        connect();
    }

    private void connect()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2024];
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sock.Connect(ip, port);

        sendRawPackets(sock, "<policy-file-request/>");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
        sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='154' /></body></msg>");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
        sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='Slime'><nick><![CDATA["+user.Text+"]]></nick><pword><![CDATA["+logkey+"]]></pword></login></body></msg>");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
        sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%1#2%-2");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
        sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#6%-1%");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
        sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#7%17610%69%0,-255,190%");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
        sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#4%3150%FlumsFountain%52.9941101744771%0%989.1726320236921%-180%0%190%");
        sock.Receive(bytes);
    }
```

But anyway, in the connect() function, that is where the packets are being sent by using the sendRawPackets() function. But for some reason, when i try to get the bytes after sending the packets, the program once again just freezes and doesn't continue.

I was wondering if there was any way to fix this problem?? Would really help if someone knows the answer. :)

*EDIT* Basically trying to use this python code and convert it into C# code but not working well for me.

```
self.sendRawPacket(s, "<policy-file-request/>")
            s.recv(2024)
            self.sendRawPacket(s, "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='154' /></body></msg>")
```

Comment: *I don't know why i put in the Thread.Sleep() functions honestly lmao*. Then stop laughing and take them out. If you don't know why they're there, don't put them there. Then use the debugger to step through the code and see exactly where it's getting stuck.

Comment: @KenWhite its not the Thread.Sleep() that is the problem for sure. i only put those there because for the game that im making this on has a limit of exploiting apis or sending packets to their server. The Thread.Sleep() is just to help prevent the limit from being reached.

Its just when im going to do sock.Receive(); and so on after sending the packet is where it freezes

Comment: I didn't say they were. I said that if you can write things like *I don't know why...lmao*, you should stop throwing random lines of code in all over the place and make an effort to understand what that code does and why you're using it instead. There's more to being a programmer than just randomly pounding on the keyboard.

Comment: @KenWhite right yes i know, sorry. Anyway i just need help in solving this. From looking in a python script (and yes i know python is different from C#), after sending a packet, the person then has the script do for example "s.recv(2024)" or instead of 2024 would be 1024 and whatever. Tried setting bytes whilst receiving but thats when it freezes. I also tried putting in a timeout but then i just get an error from that. I've been trying to do a lot of research from like 30 min videos to reading for a while about the functions and looking at other examples for code. But the code is not similar.

Comment: It should freeze because you're using `Thread.Sleep` try searching **async** methods in C#, like `Task` and `BackgroundWorker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the issue. As im trying to send packets, im doing it using UDP, and Dgram for socket type.

But what i really needed to do was change the protocoltype to Tcp and the SocketType to stream

sorry for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want not to make your UI Thread freeze

```
using System.ComponentModel;


private void connect()
{
    using(BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker())
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sock.Connect(ip, port);
        bw.DoWork += (o, e) => {
            sendRawPackets(sock, "<policy-file-request/>");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='154' /></body></msg>");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='Slime'><nick><![CDATA[" + user.Text + "]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[" + logkey + "]]></pword></login></body></msg>");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%1#2%-2");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#6%-1%");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#7%17610%69%0,-255,190%");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#4%3150%FlumsFountain%52.9941101744771%0%989.1726320236921%-180%0%190%");
            Thread.Sleep(600);
        }

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) => {
            //When all the work is finished
        }

        //Runs the background worker
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}
```

Comment: im deeply sorry for wasting ur time on trying to help me. Figured i would confuse people. I meant to put in the code for the receive in which is why it is freezing after sending packets. You can now see the edit above ^^^^. Hopefully it makes more sense.